# How to SILENTLY install WiX Toolset Build Tools v3.11?

Tags: wix, silent-installer, wix3.11

I need to install v3.11 of the [WiX Toolset Build Tools](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases) silently on a build server. Is there any documentation describing Command-Line Options for Installing the WiX Toolset v3?
I am struggling to find documentation for how to silently install wix311.exe.

I did find [this article](http://packagingstuffs.blogspot.com/2017/11/wix-toolset-311-silent-install-method.html) which says to run:

```
wix311.exe /install /quiet /norestart
```

but that does not work for me. I can see in task manager that wix311.exe briefly runs for a second but nothing is installed.

Comment: fwiw the flags you used in this question work as-is in wix 3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn supports these switches: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options, including `/silent`.

Comment: There is no `/silent` switch mentioned in that link? So is that switch valid?

Comment: `/quiet` and `/silent` are equivalent in Burn.